# HTML input form and Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, forms, google-maps

I have a simple HTML input form with a button. Fist I added javascript so the form can be submitted by pressing enter key not only by clicking button. That worked perfectly. After that I added javascript so when certain keyword is entered the user gets redirected to some other URL. Here is where the problem came. The users get redirected normally when pressing button, but when I press enter it leads me to 404 page. Here is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
function enter(e){
    if(e.keyCode == 13)
        Login();
}
//-->
</script>

 <script type="text/JavaScript">
 <!--
 function Login(){
 var keyword=document.getElementById("address").value;
 var done=0;
 keyword=keyword.toLowerCase();
 keyword=keyword.split(' ').join('');
 if (keyword=="example,example") { window.location="http://www.example.com"; done=1; }
 if (keyword=="example1") { window.location="http://www.example1.com"; done=1; }
 if (keyword=="example2") { window.location="http://www.example2"; done=1; }
 if (done==0) { codeAddress(); }
 }
 //-->
 </script> 

<form name="enterkeyword" action="none">
    <input name="keyword" id="address" type="text"  onkeypress="return enter(event);"/>
    <div class="buttons">
    <button type="button" onclick="Login()">Submit</button>
    </div>
    </form>
```

Any help?

Comment: your onkeypress JS function is called with a parameter. What is the value assigned in "event" in the function onkeypress="return enter(event)"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
function enter(e){
    if(e.keyCode == 13)
        Login();
}
//-->
</script>
```

to

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
function enter(e){
    if(e.keyCode == 13)
    {
        Login();
        return false;
    }
}
//-->
</script>
```